# restrict exe from pop up error windows

Tags: windows, error-handling, popup

hey I am trying to brute force on a challenge exe but each time that the password is wrong there is a pop up error box - "Bad Image" its supposed to happen when the password is wrong. But in order to let the brute force continue I have to manually press OK or enter to make it shut down and this happen again and again. That way the process is slower and I have to press enter the while time. Is there any way that I can disable those pop ups? I got windows 10

Comment: [*SetErrorMode*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621(v=vs.85).aspx) *(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS)*

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/how-do-i-disable-error-reporting-in-windows-2626074 i also tried this and nothing happpened